# OutputStream OutOfMemoryError when sending HTTP

Tags: java, http, out-of-memory

I am trying to publish a large video/image file from the local file system to an http path, but I run into an out of memory error after some time...

here is the code

```
public boolean publishFile(URI publishTo, String localPath) throws Exception {
    InputStream istream = null;
    OutputStream ostream = null;
    boolean isPublishSuccess = false;

    URL url = makeURL(publishTo.getHost(), this.port, publishTo.getPath());
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


    if (conn != null) {

        try {

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            istream = new FileInputStream(localPath);
            ostream = conn.getOutputStream();

            int n;
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            while ((n = istream.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                ostream.write(buf, 0, n); //<--- ERROR happens on this line.......???
            }

            int rc = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (rc == 201) {
                isPublishSuccess = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex);
        } finally {
            if (ostream != null) {
                ostream.close();
            }

            if (istream != null) {
                istream.close();
            }
        }
    }

    return isPublishSuccess;

}
```

HEre is the error i am getting...

```
Exception in thread "Thread-8773" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
    at sun.net.www.http.PosterOutputStream.write(PosterOutputStream.java:61)
    at com.test.HTTPClient.publishFile(HTTPClient.java:110)
    at com.test.HttpFileTransport.put(HttpFileTransport.java:97)
```

Comment: Some (including me) considere it rude to crosspost: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5424210 Especially when you don't even mention the fact.

Comment: Please don't take offense at the edit where I criticized your code. It is better than average, but has room for improvement. All non-trivial code does. And it's easy to mess up exception handling: I got a well-deserved -1 a week or so ago when I just typed in an example try/catch/finally without letting my compiler check it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `HttpUrlConnection` is buffering the data so that it can set the `Content-Length` header (per [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3)).

One alternative, if your destination server supports it, is to use "[chunked](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setChunkedStreamingMode(int))" transfers. This will buffer only a small portion of data at a time. However, not all services support it (Amazon S3, for example, doesn't).

Another alternative (and imo a better one) is to use [Jakarta HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/index.html). You can set the "entity" in a request from a file, and the connection code will set request headers appropriately.

---

Edit: *nos* commented that the OP could call `HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(long length)`. I was unaware of this method; it was added in 1.5, and I haven't used this class since then.

However, I *still* suggest using Jakarta HttpClient, for the simple reason that it reduces the amount of code that the OP has to maintain. Code that is boilerplate, yet still has the potential for errors:

- The OP correctly handles the loop to copy between input and output. Usually when I see an example of this, the poster either doesn't properly check the returned buffer size, or keeps re-allocating the buffers. Congratulations, but you now have to ensure that your successors take as much care.
- The exception handling isn't quite so good. Yes, the OP remembers to close the connections in a `finally` block, and again, congratulations on that. Except that either of the `close()` calls could throw `IOException`, keeping the other from executing. And the method as a whole throws `Exception`, so that the compiler isn't going to help catch similar errors.
- I count 31 lines of code to setup and execute the response (excluding the response code check and the URL computation, but including the try/catch/finally). With HttpClient, this would be somewhere in the range of a half dozen LOC.

Even if the OP had written this code perfectly, and refactored it into methods similar to those in Jakarta Commons IO, *s/he shouldn't do that*. This code has been written and tested by others. I know that it's a waste of *my* time to rewrite it, and suspect that it's a waste of the OP's time as well.

Comment: In this case, HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode could be called as well, based on the file size. This will cause the HttpUrlConnection to return a direct stream since it doesn't have to buffer to figure out the content length.

Comment: nos is right. There's absolutely no need to use a chunked request or to use 3rd party libraries for this. Simply call setFixedLengthStreamingMode with the file length on the HttpURLConnection before connecting and getOutputStream will return a non-buffering direct wrapper to the socket's OutputStream.

Comment: @jarnbjo - I'm assuming you're the person who downvoted me and everyone else who responded. And while your comments are valuable, it would have been more constructive to post them as a response.

Comment: kdgregory: No point in repeating nos' solution in my own response, would it? I don't know though why he didn't write the only reasonable solution in a response, allowing to give him proper credit for it.

Comment: @jarnbjo - You're correct. You didn't have anything constructive to add. Well, whatever makes you happy. I'm quite impressed by your upvote:downvote ratio, btw.

Comment: @kdgregory/skaffman: If my upvote/downvote ratio is indicative of something, it is that I found most responses here pretty useless for the original poster. Like in this case, a one-line modification to the posted code would solve the problem, instead you both recommend to switch use HttpClient instead. Of course it would work, it's however definitely not the easiest solution.

Comment: @jarnbjo - edited the post with some more explanation, that hopefully gives you an understanding of why a "one line modification" (it would actually be two) is "definitely not the easiest solution."

Answer (score 5):

```
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) new File(localpath).length());
```

And for buffering you could cover your streams into the *BufferedOutputStream* and *BufferedInputStream*

Good example of chunked uploading you could find there: [gdata-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/client/?r=189#client/uploader)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the HttpURLConnection class is using a byte array to store your data. Presumably this video you are pushing is taking more memory than available. You have a few options here:

1. Increase the memory to your application. You can use the -Xmx1024m option to give 1GB of memory to your application. This will increase the amount of data you can store in memory.
2. If you still run out of memory, you might want to consider trying another library to push the video up that does not store the data all in memory at once. The Apache Commons HttpClient has such a feature. See this site for more information: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/features.html. See this section for multi-part form upload of large files: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/multipartpost.html

Answer (score 2):

For anything other than basic GET operations, the built-in `java.net` HTTP stuff isn't very good. Using [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) is recommended for this. It lets you do much more intuitive stuff like this:

```
PutMethod put = new PutMethod(url);
put.setRequestEntity(new FileRequestEntity(localFile, contentType));
int responseCode = put.executeMethod();
```

which replaces a lot of your boiler-plate code.

Answer (score 2):

HttpsURLConnection#setChunkedStreamingMode(1024 * 1024 * 10); //10MB chunk
This ensures that any file (of any size) is streamed over a https connection, without internal buffering. This should be used when the file size or the content length is unknown.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is that you're trying to fix X video bytes into X/N bytes of RAM, when N > 1.

You either need to read the video into a smaller buffer and write it out as you go or make the file smaller or increase the memory available to your process.

Check your heap size.  You can use -Xmx to increase it if you've taken the default.