# Java REST API for Large file uploads

Tags: java, javascript, rest, file-upload, jersey

I'm developing a REST API using Jersey and I need to add large file uploading via REST API. I tried with small files and its working. However, the API will be used to upload large files which will have size of 2GB - 5GB, since it will be used to upload videos.

I have checked on the stack overflow and other forums to find similar questions and its been suggest to use  streaming to upload large files. I'm not sure how to write the REST API to accept such large files without timeout. I want to use both REST API and also normal file upload (via html file upload) to accept large files. I want to know how I can break files into small chunks and upload to the REST API and store the files in the server.

Are there any libraries in Javascript and Java to make this task easy?

Comment: I checked that question and its not give any details on how to upload large file with the html forms to the rest api.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look to this response [stackoverflow : uploading large files with jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326460/upload-a-large-file-using-jersey-client) (see the code of sikrip) that is similar to your problem. And here is an example [JS client code for uploading large file](http://blog.mitjagti.com/post/2012/08/10/Uploading-large-files-to-WCF-from-client-side-%28streaming-chunking%29.aspx) .

I've been testing this JS code and that's working.

Enjoy!

Comment: I checked it and there is no direct javascript code to make chunk the large file. Can you give me the exact link of that?