# how to read multipart entity from android in jersey web service

Tags: java, android, jersey, jersey-2.0

i am getting multipart entity from android client as shown below.

```
       HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
        "http://localhost:9090/MBC_WS/rest/network/mobileUserPictureInsert1");


        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("message", new StringBody("hi moni"));

        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

In jersey i am trying to retrieve message but getting only object.the code is:

```
 @Path("/mobileUserPictureInsert1")
 @POST
 @Consumes("multipart/*")

public String create(MultiPart multiPart){
     BodyPartEntity bpe = (BodyPartEntity) multiPart.getBodyParts().get(0).getEntity();
     String message = bpe.toString();
```

here i AM getting some object ony not message value. what mistake i made.pl help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the the right result. `toString()` will just use [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which will result in

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

which is most likely what you're seeing.  Unless [`BodyEntityPart`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.8/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/BodyPartEntity.html) overrides the `toString()`, which it doesn't. You should instead be getting the `InputStream` with [`BodyEntityPart.getInputStream()`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.8/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/BodyPartEntity.html#getInputStream%28%29). Then you can do whatever with the `InputStream`.

A simple example:

```
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/*")
public String create(MultiPart multiPart) throws Exception {
    String message;
    try (BodyPartEntity bpe 
                = (BodyPartEntity) multiPart.getBodyParts().get(0).getEntity()) {
        message = getString(bpe.getInputStream());
    }
    return message;
}

private String getString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

---

**On another note:**  You are already using the Jersey multipart support, you can make life easier and just use its annotation support. For instance, you can just do

```
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/*")
public String create(@FormDataParam("message") String message){
    return message;
}
```

That is much easier. The `@FormDataParam("message")` gets the body name that you defined here:

```
reqEntity.addPart("message", new StringBody("hi moni"));
```

and converts to to String. As long as there's a MessageBodyReader available for the Content-Type of the body part, it should be able to be auto-converted.

- [See more on Multipart support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart)
- [Here's another example showing a file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435)

Comment: thanks peeskillet... the first method works out very well. but @FormDataParam is not working since in android i am not using form.just using multipartentity. getting following error while running that.

Comment: That's odd. I actually tested this with your exact client code

Comment: i m getting error while running the application itself. the error is:SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771) etc.....

Comment: That's odd. That error is showing Jersey 1 classes.  You tagged Jersey 2. Look at the very last link in my answer. At the bottom, you should see the Multipart dependency. Are you sure you are using Jersey 2? The `com.sun.jersey` classes are Jersey 1

Comment: sorry i m using jersey 1.

Comment: When I have some time later I will test with Jersey 1 and give you an update.

Comment: So I was able to reproduce the problem with Jersey 1. If you change the `@Consumes` to `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` it appears to work. If you look at the headers, the client request is actually being sent out as `multipart/form-data`