# Why can't I send a multipart/form-data request to Microsoft OneNote?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, multipartform-data, onenote

I am modifying software to export client data to Microsoft OneNote instead of to local html files. I'm also *not* an experienced programmer, so I've been trying to teach myself this API and these protocols as I go along.

I am able to sucessfully use both [the Apigee interface](https://apigee.com/onenote/embed/console/onenote/) and [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) to send multipart POST requests and upload pages to a OneNote Notebook.

On hurl.it, I include two headers:

"Authorization", "myAuthCode"

"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=NewPart"

While these interfaces work fine, I am unable to replicate the process in my Java project.

Here is my test code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String tokenString = "LONG_TOKEN_STRING"

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Entity<String> payload = Entity.text("--NewPart\n" +
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Presentation\"\n" +
            "Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml\n" +
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n" +
            "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"en-us\">\n" +
            "  <head>\n" +
            ... //the rest of the POST request body is in here
            ...
            "</body></html>\n" +
            "--NewPart--\n" +
            ".\n");

    Response response = client.target("https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages")
            .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenString)
            .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=NewPart")
            .post(payload);

    System.out.println("status: " + response.getStatus());
    System.out.println("headers: " + response.getHeaders());
    System.out.println("body: \n" + response.readEntity(String.class));

    }
}
```

When I execute this code, I receive the following response:

> "code":"20110","message":"Page create requests require the content to be multipart, with a presentation part."

From this, I know that I'm successfully contacting OneNote, and successfully authenticating.

I believe that my error is in the way I set up the headers in Java. I'm unsure if you're allowed to chain .header methods. The only other way that I'm aware of is to pass a MultiValuedMap to the .headers method, though I'm unfamiliar with the interface and how to implement it.

The OneNote Dev Center is a bit unhelpful, telling me only what I already know and seem to have included in my code.

Edit:

I've updated my code with **CRLF**'s in place of single \n characters, though the problem persists:

[image: Updated Java Code]
[image: OneNote Error Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`Entity.text()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html#text%28T%29)

> Create a "text/plain" entity.

I haven't tested, but I'm guessing that this overwrites the `Content-Type` you set in the `header()` method. You can use

```
Entity.entity(entity, MediaType)
```

to create a generic entity, where you can specify the media type.

Another thing, I don't know what JAX-RS implementation you are using, but any implementation should have multipart support, so you don't to manually handle the building of the body. [Here is an example using Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435).

Comment: Thank you! I changed payload to an Entity.xhtml, and the page posts successfully to my notebook. What's interesting is that it completely disregards the part boundaries, and uploads the entire payload to a notebook page, including the part headers "Content-Disposition" and "Content-Type", in plain text.
I'm not very worried, because my html is still being pushed successfully to a page!

Answer (score 0):

You should use **CRLF `\r\n`** instead of `\n` [especially when dealing with ms/windows].

It looks like you are missing  a `\n` character at the beginning of `payload` and a **2nd** `\n` after the `\n` on the line `"Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml\n"`

sources:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt

PS the rest of your code looks good

Comment: I've replaced all of my \n characters with CRLF's.
I've also read through the documentation you've provided; thank you!
Unfortunately, even after including another CRLF before each boundary, my problem persists. I will continue to play with the escape characters throughout my code in the meantime.

[Screenshot](http://puu.sh/izLbY/fcd2620ee2.png) of my code. (Apologies, I'm unsure if screenshots are against stackoverflow question/comment etiquette.)

Comment: Hi again, there is a stray decimal point at the end of `payload`.  You should also add the `charset=[utf8|iso-8859-1]` to both your Content-Type headers.  The XML is declared as utf-8 but coming from windows it may in fact be iso-8859-1, make sure it's the right one.  You should update your code above to reflect the changes so that others can help

Comment: Maybe a last resort: if you could capture both a successful api call and a failed one with wireshark/tcpdump/etc. the problem would probably present itself more clearly.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help very much! I've been able to resolve the problem thanks to @peeskillet 's suggestion to change the entity type. There are still some strange things going on, but I will edit my original post. Thank you again!