# How test rest file upload service?

Tags: spring, rest

I created simple Rest service to upload a file (in Spring web application), method looks like below:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/job/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces({ "application/json; charset=UTF-8" })
    public Response upload(List<Attachment> attachments) {

        LOG.info("Upload new picture to!");
        // some unimportant code
 }
```

I try to test it by [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/restclient/) - Firefox plugin. When call this rest service I see : `Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type`.
[image]

How can I test it? Can I add sample file in RESTClient and how can I do it?

Comment: is this plugin supports file upload test? if you are using intellij idea , they have Rest Client for testing file upload. you can find it under Tools-> test restful Web Service.

Comment: What does the request look like? You should be able to see the complete request. That would help. You can also check out [Chrome's Postman](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435). Multipart support is pretty easy to work with.