# Create a REST API to upload Multipart file data in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, postman

I have created a rest API to accept `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` as below. But once I hit the service using Postman, I am getting HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type exception

```
@POST
@Path("/fileupload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String uploadfile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {

    System.out.println(file.getName());

    return "Success String";
}
```

What is wrong here? To consume `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`, do I need to make any modifications?
In Postman I have attached a text file in the BODY and hit the endpoint. The content type is set as "multipart/form-data"

Comment: please follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request
 It says to remove the content-type from postman.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are confused with Spring rest API with  Rest easy implementation.

1. In Resteasy, 
    Normal way to handle uploaded file is  via 
    MultipartFormDataInput  or  Map uploaded file to a 
     POJO class via @MultipartForm

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/

[How to POST a multipart/form data with files programatically in a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521518/how-to-post-a-multipart-form-data-with-files-programatically-in-a-rest-api)

2. If you want to use spring rest approach, refer here
   [Multipart File upload Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699727/multipart-file-upload-spring-boot?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You have probably imported different annotations.
Try it this way

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.*;

@PostMapping(value = "/fileupload", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String uploadfile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
    return "Success String";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look on below tutorial on uploading file in spring boot

https://devkonline.com/tutorials/content/ANGULAR-8-SPRING-BOOT-FILE-UPLOAD

Comment: This link is showing some quotes , please edit /remove this answer which isnt relevent, @Siddharth Sarathe

Comment: The above link is dead