# Jersey 2.22.1 FileDataMultiPart Header Issue

Tags: jersey, multipartform-data

Hey at the moment i try to upload some files with the jersey client api 2.22.1. I've analyzed the calls of the cms ui to write my own service. For the upload of files i need to generate following request with jersey:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarydgCBaM6oYnsWZE56
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contentItem"

{"id":2858,"properties":[{"id":5604,"alias":"dateiHochladen","value":{"selectedFiles":"uploadjava.PNG"}}],
"name":"testcms.PNG","contentTypeAlias":"DateiHochladen","parentId":2857,"action":"publish","expireDate":null,"releaseDate":null,"templateAlias":"DateiHochladen1"}
------WebKitFormBoundarydgCBaM6oYnsWZE56
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_dateiHochladen"; filename="uploadjava.PNG"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundarydgCBaM6oYnsWZE56--
```

At the moment i am able to generate the upper field, but i am not able to generate the second one with **name and filename**. Can someone give me a hint how to do this? I've already tried to set new headers, fields, parts and contentdispositions...

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435)

Comment: Thank you now i've got it working! Problem was the wrong type DataBodyPart