# How to post entity and files in the same request with jax -rs and AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, jax-rs

I'm developing a simple app with AngularJS, Spring Boot and JAX-RS, part of that app requirements is to post a product entity which must contain price, name and picture, so far I find only documentation and tutorials that show how to upload the file itself but not the entity.

I will upload the picture to aws s3, so if there is a way to send the picture outside the entity in the same post, that works fine for me.

That's it, any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by upload an entity?

Comment: Is your problem with the client side sending or the server side receiving?

Comment: Both, but I believe that if i have the backend sorted out I can solve the front end.

Comment: By uploading an entity, I mean a sending a json object from the frontend to the backend.

Comment: [Here's for your backend](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435). For the front end just search how to send a multipart request with angular. There are many articles on the web, and posts here