# How correctly provide MessageBodyWriter for FormDataMultiPart

Tags: java, maven, jersey, mailgun

I'm testing mailgun api with MIME message body.Mailgun provide an api example at https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#examples

When I run the example with my config, I got one java error message like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart.
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:393)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at com.mioying.chat.util.MailGunClient.sendEmail(MailGunClient.java:44)
at com.mioying.chat.util.MailGunClient.main(MailGunClient.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

This is my maven dependency for the project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

What other library do I need to include into the project? or Do I need to have a extra step to register the provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're trying to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is not the mime type for multipart. You should just get the media type from the FormDataMultiPart, as it will also add the boundary

   ```
   post(Entity.entity(mutliPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));
   ```
2. You need to register the `MultiPartFeature` with the `Client`

   ```
   Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
   client.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
   ```

See full example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435)

Comment: Thanks~! You save my day. Mailgun should update their example as well.