# Postman - Sending image file and json on POST

Tags: json, web-services, post, jakarta-ee, postman

I'm using Postman to test REST Web API and I have a method that receives this object:

```
public class NewShipmentDto implements Serializable {
  private String description;
  private Long senderId;
  private Long receiverId;
  private byte[] packageImage;
  private CommissionPaidBy commissionPaidBy;
  private Long senderPaymentMethod;
  private LocationDto senderLocation;
  private LocationDto receiverLocation;

// + constructors and gets/sets
}
```

So the body of my POST needs to be something like this:

```
{
    "description":"Libros",
    "senderId":1,
    "receiverId":1,
    "commissionPaidBy":"BOTH",
    "senderPaymentMethod":1,
    "senderLocation":
    {
        "latitud":100,
        "longitud":100
    },
    "receiverLocation":
    {
        "latitud":100,
        "longitud":100
    }
}
```

But I also need to send the file so it can be transformed to a `byte []`. The thing is if I use form data to pass the file how do I send this bits:

```
"receiverLocation":
{
    "latitud":100,
    "longitud":100
}
```

Is it possible to send nested json in the form data?

This is my POST method, I haven't added the logic of reading the file yet:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response addShipment(String shipment) throws EnviosYaException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    NewShipmentDto newShipmentDto = gson.fromJson(shipment, NewShipmentDto.class);
    NewShipmentResponseDto response = shipmentServices.addShipment(newShipmentDto);
    return Response.ok(gson.toJson(response)).build();
}
```

If necessary I could change the structure of the json to avoid having nested json, but I would like to know if it's possible first.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using JAX-RS for the REST API. For your use case multipart/format-data content-type is more appropriate.
Please have a look at this [JAX-RS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609569/file-upload-along-with-other-object-in-jersey-restful-web-service).

Or

If you like keep the JSON structure intact, you can store the base64 encoded data in a string for the image field. The model would looks like.

```
public class NewShipmentDto implements Serializable {
  private String description;
  private Long senderId;
  private Long receiverId;
  private String encodedPackageImage;
  private CommissionPaidBy commissionPaidBy;
  private Long senderPaymentMethod;
  private LocationDto senderLocation;
  private LocationDto receiverLocation;

  // + constructors and gets/sets
}
```