# error during multipart upload: resteasy and jersey both

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, resteasy

Could not find message body reader for type: class [Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile; of content type: multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------301800312006188885519929

Comment: You cannot use MultipartFile parameter with either Jersey or RESTEasy as that is solely meant to be used with Spring MVC. Jersey and RESTEasy both have their own multipart support and you should look at the documentation for which ever one you want to use.

Comment: if you can share any sample code snippet for resteasy/jersey, that would be really helpful. Am badly stuck and need to complete it anyhow by today eod.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435