# REST API - HTTP Status 415 - Cannot consume content type

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a `javax.ws.rs.*` REST endpoint which I am trying to upload a file with.  So the endpoint receives a document and a list of parameters.

It gets the following error:

> HTTP Status 415 - Cannot consume content type

**Question**

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how do I change my code to consume the document and paramaters?

Here is my code:

```
@POST
@Path("override")
@ApiOperation(value="Receives the override info for a trip ('overrideConclusion':'Approved'/'Reject').")
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code=200, message="Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code=404, message="Not Found")
})
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
//@Consumes({"text/*","application/*"})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response override(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String token, @Context HttpServletRequest request,
                         @ApiParam(required = true) byte[] data, @ApiParam(required = true) @QueryParam("tripId") Long tripId, @QueryParam("overrideReason") String overrideReason,
                         @QueryParam("overrideConclusion") String overrideConclusion, @QueryParam("authorizedApproverPersonId") Long authorizedApproverPersonId, @QueryParam("fileName") String fileName) {
```

I use Postman to test it:

The file to upload

[image]

The parameters

[image]

Full error:

```
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 415 - Cannot consume content type</h1>
    <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
    <p><b>type</b> Status report</p>
    <p><b>message</b> <u>Cannot consume content type</u></p>
    <p><b>description</b> <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by
            the requested resource for the requested method (Cannot consume content type).</u></p>
    <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
    <h3>JBoss Web/7.0.1.Final</h3>
</body>
```

Comment: @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) ? but you send binary data not form-data

Comment: You need to use `form-data` and implement Multipart support in your API. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435)