# Jersey 2 Client that would write the stream of data to POST call chunk by chunk

Tags: java, jax-rs, jax-ws, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I wanted to write a Jersey 2 Client that would write the stream of data to POST call chunk by chunk.

Why? , this will help me to avoid to keep the whole inputstream request data to store in disk memory before sending via a POST call.

I have searched over the net and looked into Jersey2 API as well but did not find any solution , however there are solution for server side which sends the huge response in stream and reads the same in Jersey Client by doing a GET call at Client , but I wanted send the huge payload say 1 GB of XML data as stream vis POST call.

I tried using solution given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326460/how-to-avoid-outofmemoryerror-when-uploading-a-large-file-using-jersey-client) , but this solution again uses the system memory.

I do not want to store 1GB of data in disk , instead create on-fly the 1GB request stream of data / write the 1GB data to POST call directly chunk by chunk.

Any help highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

After doing much research I found the solution and here it goes :

**First** we need to implements `javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput` as mentioned below:

```
public class JerseyStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {




    /**
     * Overriding the write method to write request data directly to Jersey outputStream .
     * @param outputStream
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws WebApplicationException
     */
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        // Write to Jersey OutputStream chunk by chunk here 
    }
}
```

**Jersey Cient code** :

```
JerseyStreamingOutput jerseyStreamingOutput =
                new JerseyStreamingOutput();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http:localhost:8080");
        response = target.path("/somepath").
                request().post(Entity.entity(jerseyStreamingOutput, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
```

So the above solution helps in saving hard disk memory by writing the request chunk by chunk to outputStream , without this approach we would end up keeping the request xml file say 1GB in hard disk.

Comment: With very large files, using jersey, this approach still gives a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space