# java nio Files.copy throwing Java heap space out of memory

Tags: java-7, java-io

I am trying to create a zip file with collection of files. I used java.nio.Files class to do this:

```
Files.copy( toBeAdded,internalTargetPath, 
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
```

It is running out of heap memory due to file size is around 670MB, so is their anyway to do copy with chunks.

Comment: found a solution?

Comment: it depends on the destination stream, for instance for HTTP streams you need to set a parameter to avoid storing the full file in memory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082057/outputstream-outofmemoryerror-when-sending-http

Answer (score 0):

You can include [commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html), specifcally, the copyLarge method does the trick:

> FileOutputStream internalTargetPathStream = new FileOutputStream(internalTargetPath);
> long size = IOUtils.copyLarge(sourceStream, internalTargetPathStream);