# Why does Files.copy cause out of memory error when creating large file

Tags: java, gzip, nio, gzipoutputstream

I have a simple method that creates a tar file with a collection of compressed files inside:

```
private byte[] gzipCompress() throws IOException {
    File source = super.getPath();
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)) {
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), gos);
    }
    
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

When the file is large (not sure of exact size 1GB maybe) - this method causes an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Seems similar to this question - [java nio Files.copy thowing Java heap space out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466755/java-nio-files-copy-thowing-java-heap-space-out-of-memory), but is there some other alternative to the `IOUtils.copyLarge` solution.

Comment: A `ByteArrayOutputStream` is a memory backed, growing, that is even array copying, data structure. No wonder. You could copy to a temporary file. Alternatively you could assume a 10% compression, and do `new ByteArrayOutputStream(100_000)` with a sufficient initial capacity reserved.

Comment: @JoopEggen Presizing the BytArrayOutputStream will likely just move the OutOfMemoryError to baos.toByteArray().

Comment: @MarkRotteveel likely as then the memory is duplicated too, however many small reallocations (much slower too), will reallocate to _more_ than needed, so instead of double memory it might be triple memory

Comment: Don't try to load entire large files into memory. At some point it *must* fail. Rethink.